# How Can Get Last Generated code in MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm

I used `MVVM` Architecture in My Project .
I have `ServiceLayer` , `ViewModel Layer` ,`Core(Entities)` and `WebApp` .
I have this method in `Product controller` :

```
var result = _productService.Add(productViewModel);
        switch (result)
        {
            case AddStatus.Successfull:
                _uow.SaveChanges();
            *** here I need product.Code
             //other case 
        }
```

and My service is :

```
  public AddStatus Add(AddProductViewModel productViewModel)
    {

        var productModel = Mapper.Map(productViewModel, new Product());
      _uow.MarkAsBaseAdded(productModel);
        return AddStatus.Successfull;
    }
```

How Can I get ProductCode  after call `_uow.SaveChanges();` in controller ?

Comment: `Code` is not Key , My key in Product Class in `guid ` and Code is an Identity field

Comment: Why don't you return a wrapper class AddObject that contains both an AddStatus and a ProductCode from the `Add` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**After _uow.SaveChanges() your model get updated automatically with new value.**

I believe productModel is the model class so productModel.code will give last instered identity value.

Comment: how can I access to `Product Model ` ?

Comment: I believe your ProductController must have access to your ProductModel class.